# {@inheritDoc} not inheriting superclass javadoc in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, inheritdoc

When I use `{@inheritDoc}` in Eclipse, the superclass' javadoc comments are not appearing in my class' javadoc.

I have the following piece of code:

```java
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public int getRowCount() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getColumnCount() {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I make sure that `rt.jar` library (which contains `javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel`) has source code and javadoc locations set, and indeed when I hover over `getRowCount()` I get the `AbstractTableModel` javadoc in a tool tip. When I generate the javadoc from Eclipse, I make sure that in the "referenced archives and projects" section that `rt.jar` is selected. But the inherit doc does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the superclass's source (in this case AbstractTableModel.java) must be on the sourcepath of javadoc. This is done in Eclipse by creating a project for AbstractTableModel and selecting it in the "Select types for which Javadoc will be generated" selection during javadoc generation.

Comment: I don't understand exactly how this should work. In my case, it seems that all the classes that extend from Android.jar have this problem. What should i do now? Create a extra project for this jar file??