# Android&Javadoc: @inheritDoc is not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javadoc

Every time i used the @inheritDoc tag in javadoc, I see the following warning (example):

```
@inheritDoc used but getCount() does not override or implement any method.
```

Does anybody know how to avoid that? I'm sure that the methods implement/override another method, because I also set the @override tag, and Eclipse doesn't complain about that.

I had a similair warning concering @link where the reference could'nt be found. This is solved by using absolute identifiers (e.g. android.content.Intent instead of Intent). Is there any similar solution to this problem?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I'm posting a version answer anyways, because if someone searches for this same problem, it is something they should check.  Apparently, there are repeated bugs with this.  I'm having no problems in 1.6.0_12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a bit strange!  Things I'd look for:

- Check that the `getCount()` method really overrides a method in some ancestor class.  (I know ... `@Override` ... but check anyway!)
- Check that the method that you are overriding actually has some javadoc.
- Check that the class containing the method you are overriding is on the source code path.  If its not, then the `javadoc` utility won't be able to extract the relevant material from the parent class source file to include in the javadoc for the child method.

(And bugs in the `javadoc` utility is another possible cause ...)

**EDIT**

The javadoc sourcepath is set using the command's "-sourcepath" option, as described [here](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#javadocoptions).  Basically, you need to tell the javadoc utility where the ZIP file containing the source code of the android classes is.

Comment: 1. checked. it really overrides something

2. checked. there is javadoc available for the method in the superclass

3. how do i actually check this?

Comment: @User Unknown: See the answer here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243063/inheritdoc-not-inheriting-superclass-javadoc-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks i read it and don't fully understand it. I left a comment there.

Answer (score 2):

If the superclass is a class in a third-party library, you need the source code in order for the @inheritDoc annotation to know where to find it.

For example, if you're trying to inherit docs from a class/interface in the J2SE libraries, you can do this by unzipping the src.zip file that ships with the SDK, and adding its path to -sourcepath. When javadoc runs on your code, it will load the doc comments from those source files as needed.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be bugs in several versions of java which would cause these errors.  So I think the first thing is to upgrade to the latest version of Java and try again.

I don't think this problem is related to your @link problem.  The @link problem is expected when you reference a class that isn't actually referenced anywhere in code in the class unless you use a full package reference to the class being referenced.